# How to sort list with two object fields?

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

Good Morning!

I'm trying to compare a list by two fields, but the result is not working, can you help me?

I have an example list:

```
Name - MesesDuracao - Buy
A    - 1            - 10
A    - 2            - 5
B    - 1            - 8
```

I would like the ordering to look like this:

```
A-1-10
B-1-8
A-2-5
```

I'm trying this way:

```
Collections.sort (testImportados, new Comparator <BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima> () {
    @Override
    public int compare (BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima p1, BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima p2)
    {    

        int comparison = p1.getMesesduration (). compareTo (p2.getMesesduration ());
        return comparison == 0? p1.getQtyBuy (). compareTo (p2.getQtyBuy ()): comparison;  

    }
});
```

However, it does only sorting by "getMesesduration ()", it is not sorting by quantity purchased.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: Please correct your code : `dateComparison` is not defined and you're using 2 diff methods  getQtyComprar  and getQtyBuy

Comment: Sorry...edited..

Answer (score 3):

```
 Collections.sort(
     testImportados, 
     Comparator.comparing(BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima::getMesesduration)
                     .thenComparing(BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima::getQtyBuy));
```

Should be the simplest way to provide the correct `Comparator`, if you are using java-8 already.

Comment: I need for Java version less than 8.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your methods.

- `getQtyComprar()` makes what?
- `getQtyBuy()` makes what?

Two methods are different i think. But you are comparing two different method call in your comparator as `p1.getQtyComprar().compareTo(p2.getQtyBuy ())`. So your final `Comparator` should be in same method usage form.

***If you wants to compare `getQtyComprar` after first comparing , code looks like ;***

```
Collections.sort (testImportados, new Comparator <BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima> () {
    @Override
    public int compare (BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima p1, BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima p2)
    {    

        int comparison = p1.getMesesduration (). compareTo (p2.getMesesduration ());
        return comparison == 0? p1.getQtyComprar (). compareTo (p2.getQtyComprar()): dateComparison;  

    }
});
```

***If you wants to compare `getQtyBuy` after first comparing , code looks like ;***

```
Collections.sort (testImportados, new Comparator <BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima> () {
    @Override
    public int compare (BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima p1, BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima p2)
    {    

        int comparison = p1.getMesesduration().compareTo(p2.getMesesduration());
        return comparison == 0? p1.getQtyBuy().compareTo (p2.getQtyBuy()): dateComparison;  

    }
});
```

As a result of my post , chose your comparing method carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to first sort by quantity then by duration.

```
Collections.sort (testImportados, new Comparator <BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima> () {
    @Override
    public int compare (BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima p1, BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima p2) {
        // first sort by quantity
        int cmp = Integer.compare(p1.getQtyBuy(), p2.getQtyBuy());

        // the quantities are the same, then sort by duration
        if (cmp == 0) {
            cmp = p1.getMesesDuration().compareTo(p2.getMesesDuration());
        }

        return cmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention, I have negative values ​​in `getQtyBuy` and it looks like the code is getting lost.

I tried this other code:

```
public class CustomerSortingComparator implements Comparator < BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima > {

  @Override
  public int compare(BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima cust1, BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima cust2) {

    // all comparison
    int compareMes = cust1.getMesesduration().compareTo(cust2.getMesesduration());
    int compareBuy = cust1.getQtyBuy().compareTo(cust2.getQtyBuy());
    int compareName = cust1.getProdname().compareTo(cust2.getProdname());

    // 3-level comparison using if-else block
    if (compareMes == 0) {
      return ((compareBuy == 0) ? compareName : compareBuy);
    } else {
      return compareMes;
    }
  }
}
Collections.sort(testImportados, new CustomerSortingComparator());
```

Continue sorting only by one parameter `getMesesduration()`

I do not understand.